# problem with JavaFX's "runtime components are missing"

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to launch my project in Eclipse from the main class and I get the error : `JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`

I've used the solution described here: https://edencoding.com/runtime-components-error/

where I changed the VM Arguments in my Run Configurations by adding:

```
--module-path C:\Users\jente\OneDrive\Documenten\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib--add-modules=javafx.controls
```

However, after applying I still get the runtime error. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

It's my first post so HelloWorld first.

I had similar problem with intellij and I tried to adapt this solution to Eclipse. I think it worked so you can try this:

First of all as it was mentioned in previous

solution you tried, add this to your VMarguments:

> --module-path "/YourPath/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

(in my case quotation marks were crucial)

then be sure that you added a library:
right click on your project folder --> properties-->Java build path --> click on "module path" --> add library --> user library --> users libraries... --> new --> type for example javaFx15 --> Add external Jars... --> select all jar in javaFx lib folder, click open and apply and close.

If it's not working yet then try to add module-info.java by:
right click on your project folder --> configure --> create module-info.java

the body should look like this:

```
module YourModuleName {

requires javafx.base;
requires javafx.graphics;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.controls;

opens YourFxmlFile;
}
```

It worked for me.
I hope it'll work you too.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid this issue is to simply use a custom Java that includes JFX. I recommend the Azul packages.

https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?version=java-15-mts&package=jdk-fx